# importing columns with empty quotations ("") in R

Tags: r, quotes

I am trying to import a data frame where one of the columns contains quotations ("").  I have tried to read.table() function using as.character like so:

```
data <- read.table('elist.txt', 
               sep = '',
               numerals = 'no.loss',
               colClasses = 'character')
```

However, this just makes the column contain a blank.  Also, I have tried to convert the column to quotations like so:

```
data$V4 <- ""
```

Which does not change anything.

How do I either import a document so it contains exactly the characters in the document or add quotation marks so that they are visible in a data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `quote` argument to `NULL` so that `read.table` would treat `""` as a literal (by default `quote = "\"'"`, which means both single and double quotes are treated as "quoting characters" instead of literal strings):

```
data <- read.table(text = 'V1 V2 V3
                   1 2 ""
                   3 4 ""
                   5 6 ""', 
                   sep = '',
                   numerals = 'no.loss',
                   colClasses = 'character',
                   header = TRUE,
                   quote = NULL)
```

To set a column equal to the literal `""`, we can wrap it with single quotes:

```
data$V4 <- '""'
```

**Output:**

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2 "" ""
2  3  4 "" ""
3  5  6 "" ""
```